# input type checkbox design issue

Tags: css

How to change the input type Checkbox border,background and compatible with every browser

I have used

```
.chkBox{
 border:1px solid red;
 background:#CC3333;
 width:15px;
 height:15px

 }
```

But i am not getting my desire out put.

Comment: duplicate question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css try googling a bit before posting one :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Checkbox** is one of the element that browsers tend not to let you style that much. for that you can use `JS` http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/

**OR**

You can achieve this with css hack check this

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you can customize the check boxes. Please go [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox)